# Can't seem to understand why my background image carousel is not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Don't understand why my Background Carousel is not working. I'm trying to place a static logo and some other components above the background carousel on my app, but I believe I have a few errors, just don't know what exactly. At the moment getting "React.createElement: type is invalid"
Any help would be appreciated.

This is my BackgroundCarousel.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, ScrollView, Dimensions, Image} from 'react-native'

const DEVICE_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;

class BackgroundCarousel extends React.Component {
    scrollRef = React.createRef();
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selectedIndex: 0
        }

    }


    render() {
        const {images} = this.props
        const {selectedIndex} = this.state
        return (
            <View style= {{height: "100%", width: "100%"}}>
                <ScrollView horizontal pagingEnabled>
                    {images.map(image => (
                        <Image
                            key={image}
                            source={{uri: image}}
                            style={styles.backgroundImage}
                        />
                    ))}
                </ScrollView>

            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
    backgroundImage: {
        height: "100%",
        width: DEVICE_WIDTH
    }

});

export { BackgroundCarousel}
```

This is my App.js file

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ImageBackground, 
  Image, TextInput, Dimensions, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from './components/button.js'
import { BackgroundCarousel } from './components/BackgroundCarousel.js'

const images = [
"./images/basketball.jpg",
"./images/network.jpg",
"./images/memories.jpg",
"./images/photographer.jpg"
];



/* Logo for login page */
import logo from './Icon/iconpersons.png'

const { width: WIDTH } = Dimensions.get('window')

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style= {styles.carouselContainer}>
      <BackgroundCarousel images={images}>

        <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
          <Image source={logo} style={styles.logo}/>
          <Text style={styles.logoText}>Hello World</Text>
        </View>

        <View>
          <TextInput 
              style={styles.input}
              placeholder={'Username'}
              placeholderTextColor={'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)'}
              underlineColorAndroid= 'transparent'

          />
        </View>

        <View>
          <Button>
            Let's Get Started
          </Button>
        </View>

        </BackgroundCarousel>
        </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

it's maybe because you are passing image source props as **source={{uri: image}}** whereas you are passing locally store images in props. what you should do is.

```
{images.map(image => (
  <Image
     key={image}
     source={require(image)}
     style={styles.backgroundImage}
   />
))}
```

or you can just edit your **images** array as:

```
const images = [
    require("./images/basketball.jpg"),
    require("./images/network.jpg"),
    require("./images/memories.jpg"),
    require("./images/photographer.jpg)"
];
```

Comment: Tried both options, didn't work. When trying the first option, I got an error that said: "BackgroundCarousel.js:invalid call at line 27"       and with the second option, I got an error that said: "JSON value '2' of type NSNumber cannot be converted to a valid URL

Comment: you're definitely right about the url, I changed it to required for source, but there seems to be more errors.

Comment: can you explain in details? or I can just help you with my code which I having using recently.

Comment: Basically trying to make an image carousel as my background, with my static logo and button on top of it. If you see the code, the first one is for my background carousel, and the bottom box of code is for the app itself with backgroundcarousel incorporated in it. I don't know where I have gone wrong though, it looks right to me.

Comment: Essentially, I have 4 images, and I want to make a background carousel to incorporate in to my app.js file as my background that I can put a static image of my logo and a button on top. The four images need a 5 second delay between each transition

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@sushantdsuwal/thrilled-coffee I tried it on snack expo seems like its woking for me

Answer (score 0):

you have some small problems. your images are static so you only should use require not uri and that solve your problem. this code bellow solve your problems.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet, Text, View, ImageBackground,
    Image, TextInput, Dimensions, Platform
} from 'react-native';
import BackgroundCarousel from './BackgroundCarousel.js'

const images = [
    require("./images/basketball.jpg"),
    require("./images/network.jpg"),
    require("./images/memories.jpg"),
    require("./images/photographer.jpg)"
];

const { width: WIDTH } = Dimensions.get('window')

export default function App() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.carouselContainer}>
            <BackgroundCarousel images={images} />
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    carouselContainer: {
        height: "100%",
        width: "100%",
        backgroundColor: '#fff'
    }

});
```

BackgroundCarousel.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, ScrollView, Dimensions, Image} from 'react-native'

const DEVICE_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;

class BackgroundCarousel extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selectedIndex: 0
        }
        scrollRef = React.createRef();
    }

    render() {
        const {images} = this.props
        const {selectedIndex} = this.state
        return (
            <View style= {{height: "100%", width: "100%"}}>
                {this.props.children}
                <ScrollView horizontal pagingEnabled>
                    {images.map(image => (
                        <Image
                            key={image}
                            source={image}
                            style={styles.backgroundImage}
                        />
                    ))}
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
    backgroundImage: {
        height: '100%',
        width: DEVICE_WIDTH
    }

});

export default BackgroundCarousel;
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort. Still not working though, tried your solution and ended up with the error: "Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.    MY GUESS IS it has something to do with ```
class BackgroundCarousel extends React.Component ``` in the BackgroundCarousel.js not working well with ``` export default function App() ``` in my App.js file

Comment: Figured it out! Was exporting as default but importing as a named component in App.js, just had to take the component out of the curly braces

Comment: yes exactly. for best practice use sevral js files for your component dont put all of them in one file.